# Apache Derby (JavaDB) fails silently at start from Windows command line

Tags: windows, derby

I'm trying to start database with:

> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\db\bin>NetworkServerControl start

No error messages, prompt returns immediately.
And **derby.log** contains only old messages. As nothing happened.
WTF? How can I debug this?

UPD: I have added tracing from https://blogs.oracle.com/wittyman/entry/debug_tracing_in_apache_derby, but derby.log is still empty.
I'm using java.exe from the same JDK (1.8.0 x64)

Comment: Something in the Windows event log?

Comment: @Uwe, I'm not sure java does write anything to event logs, but I've checked - nothing related to JavaDB in the last hour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to switch to *x86* Java version. I've tried several *x64* JDKs from 6 to 8, all had failed silently. I think it's Derby bug.

Comment: I'm glad you solved it, but I don't see how you came to the conclusion that it's a Derby bug, at least not as you described it so far. Note that "NetworkServerControl.bat" is a batch file, and has a lot of stuff in it; the first step in debugging this would be to skip the batch file and run the Derby Network Server directly with a 'java' command from the command prompt, which would tell us more about a zillion details such as which arguments you passed, what the PATH and CLASSPATH and other variable settings were, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try running

```
java -Dderby.debug.true=AssertFailureTrace -jar %DERBY_HOME%\lib\derby.jar server start
```

It may show some details.